# Microsoft App Store Submission does not have access to Email Account to test

Tags: office-store

I'm trying to get Microsoft to approve an Web addin that takes a user's email attachments and pushes them to our Web Application. We have some very robust testing notes (up to the max in the free form text box that is) and it includes access to an Office 365 mail account, which in the first submission attempt they told me was required.

In this recent attempt they sent back a response that we had incomplete testing notes:

> Your submission did not include all information needed for successful
>   verification and testing of your offer. We were unable to login to
>   your Outlook account. Please see the attached (CannotLogin) image.
>   Please include all necessary instructions and resources for successful
>   verification and testing in the Notes for certification field when
>   re-submitting your offer. The Notes for certification field is
>   available on the Review and Publish page when you are editing your
>   offer listing.

[image]

That's it. They've never made any attempt to reach out to ask to sign in, but this seems to be required in testing. I'm wondering what we do to get this submission through. Do we leave out the email account to test with completely and have them test with one of their own accounts? Or do we put instructions in our submission explicitly to reach out to us for account verification? All we need them to do to test this is have some email with some attachments and use our credentials to our hosted web app (in our testing notes) to push that information to us.

** This is Microsoft's recommended source for support, which is odd, we've tried other forums to try to reach out. I'm aware this question may be 'off topic' according to SO guidelines. I've found that they've responded on Stackoverflow in better fashion.

**** Update ****

The submission attempt failed again. We included a specific email in our submission with test data in the account. Following screenshots explain that the requirement is an Office 365 account. Are we supposed to include an Organization domain specific office 365 account?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Answer (score 0):

The validation team use their own test accounts to confirm the sign up for an account flow and the majority of the testing. If there is any features that require an account with unlocked features, say from a paid for account - that needs to be provided by the add-in submitter. If a large amount of configuration is required or a large amount of test data needs to be present in the account, they will use the provided account. They must be able to log in and use that provided account and as they validate a large amount of add-ins per day, there is no method to contact partners mid-validation. It is the add-in submitters responsibility to ensure a test account is provided and that that account can be accessed.

Comment: We updated our submission and the request was rejected, even so. Please see our edited question as it has more detail about the submission failure

Comment: You will need to provide the validation team with a method to test the add-in. They are attempting sign is as a user would. When they attempted to sign in using the test account provided with the submission, they seen the issue reported above.

Comment: "They are attempting sign is as a user would." The Test account we provided was one you can get from going out to outlook.com and signing up. That's where the majority of our clients will be accessing the addin. None of our clients will be accessing this addin from our domain exchange account. Since most of our clients will not have an office 365 account, why is there a requirement that we use an office 365 account? I've signed up with a non-Office365 account and installed addins before.

Comment: There is no requirement for a user to use an O365 account. Users that can download the add-in from Microsoft AppSource must be able to sign up for an account